# Is RSK going to be implemented on bitcoin only?

Tags: rootstock

Is RSK going to be implemented on bitcoin only ? The other hard forked bitcoins, i.e. bitcoin cash, bitcoin gold, B2X, bitcoin diamond will not have RSK implemented on them, am I correct ?

Comment: Presumably, [this](http://www.rsk.co/) is the "RSK" you are talking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would depend on the devs of said fork. (And the devs of RSK aswell probably)

I for one have not really looked into who supports what, but a quick google search hinted me that Bitcoin Cash for example, (https://twitter.com/viabtc/status/896016235816562688) might have interest in implementing RSK aswell.

I wouldn't be so quick to argue that this couldn't / won't be implemented in other bitcoin forks.